# How to pass data from child component to parent component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I am very new to React JS. I am having a hard time understanding how to grab data from a component.

I want to be able to grab the selected dates and output the date to the console, I am using [react-datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker)

**This is DateOptions.jsx**

```
var DateOptions = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      startDate: moment(),
      endDate: moment()
    };
  },

  handleChangeStart: function(date) {
    this.setState({
    startDate: date
    });
  },

  handleChangeEnd: function(date){
    this.setState({
    endDate: date
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
          <label>Start Date:</label>
          <DatePicker
            selected={this.state.startDate}
            selectsStart  startDate={this.state.startDate}
            endDate={this.state.endDate}
            onChange={this.handleChangeStart}
          />
          <label>End Date:</label>
          <DatePicker
            selected={this.state.endDate}
            selectsEnd  startDate={this.state.startDate}
            endDate={this.state.endDate}
            onChange={this.handleChangeEnd}
          />
      </div>
     )
  }
});
```

**Then in my Main.jsx**

```
var Main = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return <DateOptions/>
  }
})
```

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Data from `child component`, u need to use `props`, `props` are used to pass the `data` or `methods` from `parent component` to `child component`.

**Step1:** Pass a function from parent component to child component, like this:

```
var Main = React.createClass({

  getData:function(data){
      console.log(data);
  },

  render: function(){
    return <DateOptions getData={this.getData}/>
  }
})
```

**Step2:** In `child component` use this `method` to pass data back to `parent component`, like this:

```
var DateOptions = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      date: moment()
    };
  },

  handleChange: function(date) {
    this.setState({
      date: date
    });
    this.props.getData(date);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
          <DatePicker
            selected={this.state.date}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
      </div>
     )
  }
});
```

Check the `jsfiddle` for similar example for input element, u will get the idea how it works : https://jsfiddle.net/m933qjvk/

Comment: Hey! This works! Thank you very much Mayank, I will look more into props